# Sonarqube: How to ignore/skip scanning of issues on certain annotation "ex. @generated" in java

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

We are generating java codes via EMF. We want Sonar to skip issue scanning on the codes with annotations `@generated` but will scan `@generated NOT` for both class and method level.

Is there a way to do that in SonarQube and SonarLint? Also, can it be applied in other annotation?

Answer (score 1):

There is the ability to ignore issues on blocks, but those blocks must have both start *and* end delimiters.

Alternately, you can ignore issues on files based on a regex of the file contents, or you can ignore issues on files based on path/name.

[The docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) can give you the details, as can browsing the interface. From your project: **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope**

Comment: Thanks on your response.
And I understand the guidelines in the doc. However, we don't want to add start and end delimiters on the chunk of codes generated for a thousands of codes. We want to skip only the classes or methods that are annotated with "@generated" but not the whole file. Please let me know if that is possible in Sonarqube.

Some of our codes are annotated with "@generated NOT" which should also be scanned for issues. 

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Sonar provides now a solution see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368480/sonarjava-71-exclude-issues-on-generated-code-when-annotated-with-javax-annotati