# SonarJava-71 Exclude issues on generated code when annotated with javax.annotation.Generated

Tags: java, sonarqube

I see this **https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-71** improvement which the current status is closed. I was asked to raise my question here.

I would like to know how to implement the fix because i tried to use latest SonarJava 4.10.0.10260, however it still reports issues on class/methods with @generated annotation. Please advise how to implement this fix. Which version of SonarJava release this fix is included. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[SONARAVA-71](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-71) has been implemented in version 4.9 of the SonarJava Analyzer, so your version of SonarJava should ignore such annotated elements if configured correctly.

Now, in order to have classes ans methods annotated with (and only with) `@javax.annotation.Generated` being ignored by the analyzer, be sure to [provide the bytecode for your analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode).